# How to give path to an text file in Solution using XDocument?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin

I want to load a xml document Swedish.xml which exists in my solution. How can i give path for that file in Xamarin.android

[image]

I am using following code:

```
 var text = File.ReadAllText("Languages/Swedish.txt");
 Console.WriteLine("text: "+text);
```

But i am getting Exception message:

```
 Could not find a part of the path "//Languages/swedish.txt".
```

I even tried following lines:

```
 var text = File.ReadAllText("./Languages/Swedish.txt");

 var text = File.ReadAllText("./MyProject/Languages/Swedish.txt");

 var text = File.ReadAllText("MyProject/Languages/Swedish.txt");
```

But none of them worked. Same exception message is appearing. Build Action is also set as Content. Whats wrong with the path? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does Swedish.xml have it's Build Action set to "Content"?

Comment: No. I did it now and now its giving directory not found exception. Thanks for help. But whats wrong with path?

Answer (score 1):

Just try with this

```
 string startupPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName, "Languages", "Swedish.txt");

 var text = File.ReadAllText(startupPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)+"/Languages/Swedish.txt"
```

Comment: This would only work if he had written the file to MyDocuments.  Just bundling a file as content from the IDE will not copy it to MyDocuments or any other special folders.

Comment: It copies it to the application folder. I'm aware.  But if I remember right, when I've used MyDocuments, or one of those other special environment folders, I was writing to the Application install location..

Answer (score 0):

If you mark a file as Content Type, it will be included in the app bundle with the path that you are using within your project file.  You can inspect the IPA file (it's just a renamed zip) that is created to verify that this is happening.

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("Languages/Swedish.txt");
```

should work.  The file path is relative to the root of your application.  You need to be sure that you are using the exact same casing in your code that the actual file uses.  In the simulator the casing will not matter, but on the device the file system is case sensitive, and mismatched casing will break the app.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into this before and never found any solution to access files in this way. All roads seem to indicate building them as "content" is a dead end. You can however place them in your "Assets" folder and use them this way. To do so switch the "Content" to "AndroidAsset".

After you have done this you can now access the file within your app by calling it via

```
var filename = "Sweedish.txt";
string data;
using
  (var sr = new StreamReader(Context.Assets.Open(code)))
            data = sr.ReadToEnd();
 ....
```